# @RequestParam dynamic parameter list as Map

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC I can create an array or a List of request parameters using `@RequestParam List<String> params`. But how can I create a Map of parameters?

I want to send dynamic parameters like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="params[some]" value="a">
<input type="hidden" name="params[thing]" value="b">
<input type="hidden" name="params[here]" value="c">
```

AFAIK `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` is doing something else. It maps all GET parameters to this Map object.

How to map those key value parameters to a @RequestParam?

Comment: do you attach these values as query params? Like `/api?some=a&thing=b&here=c` and is it for a HTTP `GET` or `POST` from your UI?

Comment: All variables are posted. Actually I use a workaround. I use the map with all parameters, whcih is filled with POST variables too. I filter it and parse my params[] with regex. Not very nice but it works. But I'm wondering there is no better way to do it.